# Undefined Step definitions in Cucumber Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

I added the login steps in Login class. But when I run the scenario from the Login.feature file I still get undefined steps error.

Login class

```
package stepDefinitions;

import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class Login {

    @Given("I am on the login page")
    public void ı_am_on_the_login_page() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }

    @When("I enter a correct e-mail address")
    public void ı_enter_a_correct_e_mail_address() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }

    @And("I enter a correct password")
    public void ı_enter_a_correct_password() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }

    @And("I click on login button")
    public void ı_click_on_login_button() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }

    @Then("I should be presented with successful login message")
    public void ı_should_be_presented_with_successful_login_message() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }

}
```

This is my Login.feature file

```
Feature: Login page

  Scenario: Successful login test
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter a correct e-mail address
    And I enter a correct password
    And I click on login button
    Then I should be presented with successful login message
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Segmentify_Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This is the project format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebuef.png)

I receive the following error when I run the scenario from Login.feature

Step undefined
You can implement this step and 4 other step(s) using the snippet(s) below:

```
@Given("I am on the login page")
public void ı_am_on_the_login_page() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```

Comment: If you look at the run configuration in IDEA, does it include a glue path?

Comment: It didn't include anything. So I added a glue path as C:/----/src/test/java/stepDefinitions. This time I received this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The glue path must have a classpath scheme C:/----/src/test/java/stepDefinitions

Comment: Try a package name. So `stepDefinitions`

Comment: I still get the first error: Step undefined. You can implement this step and 4 other step(s) using the snippet(s) below:

Comment: Try this. https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/ be sure to follow it and not use IDEA. Then make small changes until it matches your project or stops working.

Comment: Please share your runner class

Answer (score 0):

I got an error similar to this.
I tried different solution, like edit configuration. But when i create runner class and run it, the feature started working without any problem.

My runner class

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features ="C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Selenium\\com.cucumber\\src\\test\\resources\\features"
,glue = "stepDefinition")
public class testRunner {
}
```